# Replace only the zeros that a user inputs in c

Tags: c, arrays

I want to replace only a particular number which is zero which the user has entered in to a different number. here is my code so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int figOutVar[9][9];
    printf("please enter the figure me out numbers\n");
    for(int i=0; i<9; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<9; j++) {
            printf("enter %d %d: ",i+1,j+1);
            scanf("%d",&figOutVar[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("the figure me out question is: \n");
    for(int i=0; i<9; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<9; j++) {
            if (figOutVar[i] == 0) {
                return true;
            }
            if(j!=0) {
                printf(" | ");
            }
            if(j==3) {
                printf(" | ");
            }
            if(j==6) {
                printf(" | ");
            }
            printf("%d",figOutVar[i][j]);

        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled with an input

```
0 | 4 | 0 |  | 2 | 0 | 0 |  | 5 | 0 | 3
3 | 0 | 0 |  | 9 | 0 | 0 |  | 7 | 1 | 0
7 | 6 | 0 |  | 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 0 | 0 | 0
5 | 0 | 1 |  | 0 | 0 | 8 |  | 9 | 0 | 0
0 | 0 | 0 |  | 5 | 0 | 3 |  | 0 | 0 | 0
0 | 0 | 4 |  | 1 | 0 | 0 |  | 6 | 0 | 2
0 | 0 | 0 |  | 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 0 | 9 | 4
0 | 8 | 3 |  | 0 | 0 | 4 |  | 0 | 0 | 5
4 | 0 | 5 |  | 0 | 0 | 1 |  | 0 | 8 | 0
```

I want to replace the zeros that the user input into a particular number or variable, the zeros represent blank spaces or unfilled answer.
Really looking forward for your help, and Thanks.

Comment: What is your desired output ?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a Sudoku puzzle?  Are you asking how to solve it?  If so, the question is way to broad.

Comment: `for(int j=0;j<9;j++)` what is the point of this?

Comment: Simply use an if statement when printing? `if(x==0) print(something); else print(x);` This is very fundamental stuff.

Comment: `j` is not declared, and you have an unmatched `}` (2nd from last).  This is likely not the code you are actually using if you say it compiles.  And your indents are inconsistent throughout.  (Edited to at least match indents, which helps to see other problems in your code.)  Also, the minimum prototype for `main` is `int main(void) {...`

Comment: Thank you All for your feed back  will look to the future and try to improve up on all my flaws that you have described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is as simple as it looks, the answer should be too. Simply run a for, checking for zeros in your array.

```
for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
        if(figOutVar[i][j] == 0){
           figOutVar[i][j] = //here you can replace the zero with something else
        }
    }
}
```

Or, if you don't want in fact replace the original value, you could just print something else when the code find a zero.